# Print doesn't work after import in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new to Python, but want to run script from server.
So, I have following structure

```
project
-A1
--A1.py
--A2.py
-B1
--B1.py
--B2.py
-test.py
```

Also there is `__init__.py` in each subdirectory

In test.py I have simple code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print 'A'
from project import *
print 'B'
```

But `B` is not shown on page.
Maybe I do something wrong with import?

Note, that I copied files, instead of installing them. Maybe this is the reason? Maybe I should add something into system path?
I don't want to install, because in future I will need to change those files.

Maybe problem is in file persmissions. I had 644 and changed to 755, but that doesn't help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without knowing what's in "project" it's hard to say for sure, but the most likely possibility I can think of is that somewhere in the "project" module someone redirected stdout.  Can you share the source for that?

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, test.py is in the project directory? How is `from project import *` not generating an import error? You're wanting something like import A1 import B1

Comment: It is actually sympy (library for math). There are only functions as far as I know. By the way. everything is working on localhost.

Comment: First, try to run the script from your _shell_, before trying to access them using a web browser as it appears to be the case.`python test.py` should be enough.

Comment: Not working. I even tried python /sympy/test.py. location of files is public_html/sympy/test.php

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Works with public_html/sympy/test.py. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "public_html/sympy/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import core
  File "/home2/emathhel/public_html/sympy/core/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .sympify import sympify
  File "/home2/emathhel/public_html/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .core import all_classes as sympy_classes
  File "/home2/emathhel/public_html/sympy/core/core.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sympy.core.compatibility import cmp
ImportError: No module named sympy.core.compatibility

Comment: You don't have sympy installed on your remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your script doesn't complete successfully, (it raises an exception because sympy isn't installed), you do not see any output on the browser because the request doesn't complete.

If you were to check your server's error logs, you will see entries there reflecting this.

To fix the problem, install sympy - then make sure your script runs without errors from the command line, and only then access it from the browser.

Comment: Can I do it without install?

Comment: You don't have to install it for the whole server, you can install it only for your account by using a [virtual environment](http://virtualenv.org). If you can't install any packages, then you need to remove the import line in order for your file to work.

Comment: So, just to remove all imports from all files?

Answer (score 0):

Check `sys.stdout` before and after the import.
Also, try calling `sys.stdout.flush()` after the second print line.